# I am trying to select xml tag attribute values from lookup xml if at least two of the attributes match the actual xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is the orginal xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:transformOutput xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects">
    <p:objectSet>
        <p:objects>
            <p:object>
                <p:objectAttributes>
                    <p:objectType>buoybcnp</p:objectType>
                    <p:attribute name="ssc">10</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="btc">0</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="col">Fl(2+1) G</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="ns2">53</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="br2">13</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="vrr">4</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="object_code">BC020</p:attribute>
                </p:objectAttributes>
            </p:object>
        </p:objects>
    </p:objectSet>
</p:transformOutput>
```

Here is my is file look up xml

```
<Templates>
    <Template>
        <ObjTmplId>100</ObjTmplId>
        <AttTmplId>378</AttTmplId>
        <Is_Ingest>0</Is_Ingest>
        <System_Name>DNC</System_Name>
        <System_Category>ALL</System_Category>
        <System_Class>buoybcnp</System_Class>
        <System_Table>BC020</System_Table>
         <System_Attribute>hdp</System_Attribute>
        <System_Value>NaN</System_Value>
        <Condition>vrr!=4</Condition>
    </Template>
     <Template>
        <ObjTmplId>100</ObjTmplId>
         <AttTmplId>378</AttTmplId>
        <Is_Ingest>0</Is_Ingest>
         <System_Name>DNC</System_Name>
        <System_Category>ALL</System_Category>
        <System_Class>buoybcnp</System_Class>
         <System_Table>BD140</System_Table>
         <System_Attribute>hdp</System_Attribute>
        <System_Value>NaN</System_Value>
        <Condition>vrr=4 or 2</Condition>
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <ObjTmplId>100</ObjTmplId>
        <AttTmplId>378</AttTmplId>
        <Is_Ingest>0</Is_Ingest>
        <System_Name>DNC</System_Name>
        <System_Category>ALL</System_Category>
        <System_Class>buoybcnp</System_Class>
        <System_Table>BC020</System_Table>
        <System_Attribute>hdp</System_Attribute>
        <System_Value>NaN</System_Value>
     </Template>
 </Templates>
```

I tried to use transformation for the above to xmls if  System_Class and System_Table matches with the first xml values, output the rest of the attributes with the first xml file attributes. And also if there is a condition in the look up file, use output the attributes for that condition

Here is my xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects"
        exclude-result-prefixes="p">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:variable name="objectPath" select="document('lookups.xml')/Templates"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="valuePath"  select="p:transformOutput/p:objectSet/p:objects" />

    <xsl:key name="template" match="Template" use="System_Class" />
    <xsl:key name="template" match="Template"  use= "System_Table" />

    <xsl:template match="/p:transformOutput/p:objectSet">
        <objects>
            <xsl:for-each select="p:objects/p:object">
                <xsl:variable name="objType" select="p:objectType" />
                <xsl:variable name="matchFcode"  select="p:objectAttributes/p:attribute/f_code" />
                <object type="{$objType}">
                    <template>
                        <!-- switch context to the lookup file in order to use key -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="document('templates.xml')">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="key('template', $objType)/System_Value"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </template>
                </object>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </objects>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is the expected output

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><fme:xml-tables xmlns:fme="http://www.safe.com  /xml/xmltables" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://cfpe      /export       /objects" xmlns:exp="http://cfpe/export/objects">
        <fme:buoybcnp>
      <fme:ssc>10</fme:ssc>
      <fme:btc>0</fme:btc>
      <fme:ccc>27</fme:ccc>
      <fme:nam>C</fme:nam>
       <fme:eol>0</fme:eol>
       <fme:lvn>5</fme:lvn>
       <fme:per>6.000000</fme:per>
      <fme:col>Fl(2+1) G</fme:col>
      <fme:ns2>53</fme:ns2>
       <fme:br2>13</fme:br2>
       <fme:hdp>Nan</fme:hdp>
      </fme:buoybcnp</fme>
```

The values should be added once the Sysem_Class and System_Table matches but/and if the condition exists for some of the values

Comment: Please post the expected output of your example. -- Note: you cannot have two keys with the same name. -- Note 2: **nothing** in your first XML file matches any System_Class value in the second file.

Comment: I have added the matching System_class value and the expected result

Comment: The expected result does not represent valid XML and there is still no obvious match between input XML and mapping XML. Could you double check?

Comment: I am sorry, my last update wasn't captured right. it's updated now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer:

> The values should be added once the Sysem_Class and System_Table
>   matches

I *think* you'll need to redefine the key element as:

```
<xsl:key name="template" match="Template"  use= "concat(System_Class, '|', System_Table)" />
```

The next thing you need to change is the call of the key() function. I am afraid I can't help you there, because I don't understand the condition.

Your title says:

> if **at least two** of the attributes match

Then you say:

> if System_Class and System_Table matches with the **first** xml values

and finally you say:

> once the Sysem_Class and System_Table matches but/and if the condition
>   exists for **some** of the values

None of that is very clear, I am afraid. Do you want to lookup the template if **any two** of the objectAttributes, **in any order**,  match both System_Class and System_Table? That may be possible - but it doesn't sound reasonable.

---

### Edit:

I am going to take a wild guess here, hoping that this might somehow be close to what you mean:

Given this **input XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p:transformOutput xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects">
    <p:objectSet>
        <p:objects>
            <p:object>
                <p:objectAttributes>
                    <p:objectType>a</p:objectType>
                    <p:attribute name="x">F600</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="y">A100</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="z">D400</p:attribute>
                </p:objectAttributes>
            </p:object>
            <p:object>
                <p:objectAttributes>
                    <p:objectType>b</p:objectType>
                    <p:attribute name="x">F600</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="y">C300</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="z">B200</p:attribute>
                </p:objectAttributes>
            </p:object>
            <p:object>
                <p:objectAttributes>
                    <p:objectType>b</p:objectType>
                    <p:attribute name="x">a</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="y">A100</p:attribute>
                    <p:attribute name="z">B200</p:attribute>
                </p:objectAttributes>
            </p:object>
        </p:objects>
    </p:objectSet>
</p:transformOutput>
```

and a second file named **templates.xml**:

```
<Templates>
    <Template>
        <System_Class>a</System_Class>
        <System_Table>A100</System_Table>
        <System_Attribute>aA</System_Attribute>
    </Template>
    <Template>
        <System_Class>b</System_Class>
        <System_Table>B200</System_Table>
        <System_Attribute>bB</System_Attribute>
    </Template>
</Templates>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:p="http://cfpe/export/objects"
exclude-result-prefixes="p">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/p:transformOutput/p:objectSet">
    <objects>
        <xsl:for-each select="p:objects/p:object">
            <object type="{p:objectAttributes/p:objectType}">
                <xsl:variable name="attributes" select="p:objectAttributes/*" />
                <xsl:variable name="matching-template" select="document('templates.xml')/Templates/Template[System_Class=$attributes and System_Table=$attributes]" />
                <template>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$matching-template/System_Attribute"/>
                </template>
            </object>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </objects>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
   <object type="a">
      <template>
         <System_Attribute>aA</System_Attribute>
      </template>
   </object>
   <object type="b">
      <template>
         <System_Attribute>bB</System_Attribute>
      </template>
   </object>
   <object type="b">
      <template>
         <System_Attribute>aA</System_Attribute>
         <System_Attribute>bB</System_Attribute>
      </template>
   </object>
</objects>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. CONDITION: Is when the value of the attributes from xml file is equal/not with the condition value in the look up file to be added in the output file if the value of System_Class and System_table matches. I don't think the order really matters in this case. Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3983344 I am sorry, I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @user3983344 Have a look at the edit I have added to my post - maybe(!) that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks that's a big help